# two way synchronization (resolving time dependency)

Tags: javascript, ios, time, synchronization

i need to do a clent server two way sync of data with respect to "time modified" property pushed into table on either side. however i am afraid that if user changes time in their device it will lead to chaos . how do i get rid of it?

(I need to depend on client side time machine to get hold of knowing the time when data is modified as this system has to work onOFFline mode too)

(Is there any way to get hold of actions when user attemots to change time in their device)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all specifics of your system but I think you’d better use some auto-generated incrementing value (like [rowversion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) aka *timestamp*) managed by your server for your synchronization rather than depends on the “modified time” field. This way you will avoid client / server time synchronization challenges.

Recently I blogged about some sync algorithm for client / server model ([sync algorithm for exchanging data in the “Client – Server” model via REST API](http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html)). 
That might give you some ideas.

Comment: even they rely on the assumption that user side time will be correct.! thats not really reliable !

Comment: yes, but you can when you send your data, assign a timestamp to the "payload" and when you receive you get that same timestamp and then send again that one, and the new one.. to see if they modify.